# Why automatic modelstate returns 400 status code instead of 422?

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, asp.net-core-webapi, .net-6.0

I have this code which uses data annotation as validation.

```cs
[Route("api/[controller]")]
[ApiController]
public class AccountController : ControllerBase
{
    private readonly IAccountService _accountService;


    /// <param name="accountService"></param>
    public AccountController(IAccountService accountService)
    {
        _accountService = accountService;
    }

    [HttpGet]
    [Route("IsAccountClosed/{nric}")]
    public async Task<ActionResult> IsAccountClosed([Required] string nric)
    {
      // code removed for brevity
    }
}
```

When I test it by passing it empty string (with a space), it returns a 400 status code. Below is the output in swagger.

[image]

My question is why by default it returns 400 status code instead of 422 status code which is more accurate status code? How do I change it to 422 status code with the content-type still `application/problem+json`?

After applying the suggestion from Yong Shun, I can 422 status code and content-type is `application/problem+json` but the response body is different as shown below.

[image]

Comment: Hi, just want to clarify are you using the .NET framework or .NET Core or above for the web API?

Comment: Net core . Net 6

Comment: Because ASP.NET team is confused. You'll need to manually set the invalid response generation through the factory as mentioned in the answer below.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**Update**

After doing some research and trial and error,

This is how [`InvalidModelStateResponseFactory`](https://github.com/dotnet/aspnetcore/blob/082e718c9a3f08c9438423ef2da99f12a94b6952/src/Mvc/Mvc.Core/src/DependencyInjection/ApiBehaviorOptionsSetup.cs#L22-L31) generates the response with status: 400.

For your case you want to override the `statusCode` only but remain the response structure.

To implement:

1. Get `ProblemDetailsFactory` service.
2. Create `ValidationProblemDetails` (which is the structure for invalid model state response body) by providing the current HttpContext, ModelState and 422 status code (without this the `status` in the response body will be default as 400).
3. Lastly, create `BadRequestObjectResult` and provide the status code as 422.

```cs
builder.Services.AddControllers()
    .ConfigureApiBehaviorOptions(options =>
        options.InvalidModelStateResponseFactory = context =>
        {
            var problemDetailsFactory = context.HttpContext.RequestServices.GetRequiredService<ProblemDetailsFactory>();
            ValidationProblemDetails problemDetails = problemDetailsFactory.CreateValidationProblemDetails(context.HttpContext, context.ModelState, 422);

            return new ObjectResult(problemDetails)
            {
                StatusCode = 422
            };
        }
    );
```

[image]

Comment: Now it returns as 422 but its response content-type become `application/json` instead of  `application/problem+json`

Comment: Didn't test the code, but I think you can try set the contenttype with `new UnprocessableEntityObjectResult(context.ModelState) { ContentTypes = { "application/problem+json" } }`

Comment: Now its content-type is "application/problem+json" but the response body is different from what is expected. I updated my post to show the response body.

Comment: Hi, sorry for that, I update my answer. Thanks.

Comment: Cool, it works as expected. Thanks @Yong Shun